# order posts by first category names (A-Z) wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have products and each product belongs to some categories. I need to get each product's first category name and order posts by those category titles.

From the very beginning, I have comma separated specific post Ids(`$productIds`) for which I need to do the sorting. I did below:

```
$productIds = $_POST['productIds'];
$finalProductIds = explode(',', $productIds);

foreach($finalProductIds as $id) {
    /*$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'DESC', 'fields' => 'all');*/
    $args = array('fields' => 'all');
    $taxonomy = 'product-category';
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $id, $taxonomy, $args );
    $term = $terms[0];
    echo $term->name.',';
}
```

So with above code I could find first category names(`$terms[0]`) but can't order them/their posts alphabetically? Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to list them like this:

Post A - Cat X
Post B - Cat X
Post C - Cat Y
Post D - Cat Z
Post E - Cat Z?

Comment: Yes, but I don't need post titles to be ordered alphabetically too. I only need to order posts by first category names @MirzaP

Comment: Perhaps this is the solution you need:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142268/order-posts-by-category-name

Comment: thanks but it didn't help, my case is a bit different @MirzaP

Comment: @aidadev did you foud a solution